# Is it possible to get similar text in string by RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to make function to get similar text in string by RegExp ex:

max differences letters = 2 or 3 letters ( + or - ) will be fine

```
var text = 'Is it possible to get similar text in string by RegExp';
// and
similar_text(text , 'strong'); // => string
similar_text(text , 'posible'); // => possible
similar_text(text , 'isit'); // => Is it
// etc...
```

Comment: how do you define similar text?

Comment: if max differences letters = 2 or 3 letters ( + or - ) will be fine

Comment: I think RegExp itself can only be used to check that texts are all match some pattern. But in order to detect that two strings are only differ for at most 2 or 3 letters, you should write a custom function to handle it. I do some search and find this one, you can have a look. http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-javascript-compare-differences-between-strings.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my implementation (Needs [Levenshtein](https://github.com/gf3/Levenshtein) function). Not the prettiest, but it gets the job done:

```
  function similar_text(haystack, needle) {
    let best_match = false;
    let best_match_int = 9007199254740992;

    let arr = haystack.split(" ");

    haystack = haystack.toLowerCase();
    needle = needle.toLowerCase();

    for (let chunk = 1; chunk < arr.length; chunk++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i + chunk > arr.length)
          continue;

        let subStack = arr.slice(i, i + chunk).join(' ');
        let l = new Levenshtein(needle, subStack);

        if (l.distance < best_match_int) {
          best_match = subStack;
          best_match_int = l.distance;
        }
      }
    }

    return best_match;
  }
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Y8o5ImVFvA4ySyriEpJ?p=preview) demoing how this can be done.